# Declaration inside eval in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

Consider the following two JavaScript snippets:

```
var x = 2;
function f() {
    var y = x;
    eval('var x;');
    return y;
}
```

vs.

```
var x = 2;
function f() {
    var y = x;
    var x;
    return y;
}
```

The only difference is I've replaced `eval('var x;');` with `var x;`.

The first one returns `2`, but the second one returns `undefined`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable declarations are **hoisted** by the parser to the top of the lexical scope. In the second block of code, the way it's actually run is:

```
function f() {
  var x, y;
  y = x;
  return y;
}
```

Function declarations are also hoisted.  The net effect is that a variable declaration should be considered to always include the entire lexical scope in which it appears. If variable `x` is declared with `var` **anywhere** in a function, then every reference to `x` in that function is to the local variable.

In your first example, the `eval()` line is just a regular expression statement, so it's executed in order of its appearance in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because with the second one, the `var` is hoisted* to the beginning of the function, before any other statements are executed.

So its as though you code was this:

```
var x = 2;
function f() {
    var x, y
    y = x;
    return y;
}
```

But with the first one, the `var x` is part of the `eval()` expression, so it doesn't have the opportunity to be hoisted* as in the second one.

---

*The term "hoisted" is not an official term. Its just a word that people use to describe the fact that declarations happen before any expressions are evaluated within the execution context. Function declarations are also hoisted.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when the interpreter is in scope of function it sets value `undefined` to all variables which are declared inside it (with `var` keyword prefixed). It's no matter where you've put the declaration, if there's a variable declaration inside a function the variable's value will be `undefined` until you set it's value explicitly. In the first case you have `eval('var x;')` which is still not evaluated when the value of `y` is being set. That's why the value of `y` is `2`, because the value of the variable `x` in the upper scope is `2`.
The same will be here:

```
var x = 2;
function foo() {
    var y = x;
    console.log(y); //undefined
    console.log(x); //undefined
    var x = 3;
}

function bar() {
    var y = x;
    console.log(y); //2
}
```

---

```
var x = 2;
function foobar() {
    console.log(x); //undefined
    var x;
    console.log(x); // undefined
    x = 3;
    var y = x;
    console.log(y); //3
}
```

The eval is evaluated just as a regular expression.